# What are Palomena prasina doing in my home?

Tags: entomology

I live in eastern Europe, and every autumn, ever so often a *Palomena prasina* flies inside my home.

I have an avocado plant that I put them on to live - I currently have 5 of these on my plant

However, I have noticed they hardly if ever eat the plant and they hardly if ever move, and I haven't noticed poo either (they are alive). I was thinking that they are waiting the winter to pass and kind of hibernate, but if this is the case, firstly - how can they tell, and secondly - isn't their lifespan too short to wait for the spring?

Comment: Many people call many different things 'stink bugs.' You will have to be more precise with what bug you are referring to (species ideally, genus is probably okay). I don't know if they can be "hibernating" (overwintering) on your indoor plant - is your indoor avocado plant kept at room temperature?

Comment: I believe it is Palomena prasina